# How to pass Integer value to kafka producer and read it back on kafka consumer console using IntegerSerializer in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to send Integer value through Kafka producer using the kafka provided API IntegerSerializer,but the integer value is not getting parsed correctly and it displayed in form of random unknown symbol on the Kafka consumer console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    int i;
    // Check arguments length value
    if(args.length == 0){
       System.out.println("Enter topic name");
       return;
    }

    //Assign topicName to string variable
    String topicName = args[0].toString();

    // create instance for properties to access producer configs   
    Properties props = new Properties();

    //Assign localhost id
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

    //Set acknowledgements for producer requests.      
    props.put("acks", "all");

    //If the request fails, the producer can automatically retry,
    props.put("retries", "0");

    //Specify buffer size in config
    props.put("batch.size"," 16384");

    //Reduce the no of requests less than 0   
    props.put("linger.ms", "1");

    //The buffer.memory controls the total amount of memory available to the producer for buffering.   
    props.put("buffer.memory", "33554432");

    props.put("key.serializer", 
       "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    props.put("value.serializer", 
       "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");

    KafkaProducer<String,Integer> producerRcrd = new KafkaProducer<String,Integer>(props);
    producerRcrd.send(new ProducerRecord<String,Integer>(topicName, "Key1",100));
    System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
    producerRcrd.flush();
    producerRcrd.close();

 }
}
```

Then  it is not showing 100 on Kafka-consumer console.

Answer (score 2):

Appending

```
--property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
```

to `kafka-console-consumer.sh`, having console message formatter know how to deserialize your message body.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to send integer value through using above mentioned java code. In this java code sample, I am using IntegerSerializer for value to send the integer but it is not working.

Comment: Though, I can easily send integer value from producer console to consumer console of kafka. But I am facing issue while I am trying to do this through java code.Please suggest.

Comment: I was just following your usage and got successful. How did you run the console consumer?

Comment: kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <<topicname>>

Comment: Try this: kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic <topicname> --from-beginning --property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer

Comment: I tried your suggested command but it is giving ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <topicname> --from-beginning --property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kakfa.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kakfa.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)

Comment: What's your Kafka version?

Comment: Kafka version is :--  2.11-0.10.1.0

Comment: A typo: org.apache.`kakfa`.common. Correct it.

Comment: After trying the above command, it is giving following error:-
Processed a total of 1 messages
[2017-03-02 11:38:30,844] ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by IntegerDeserializer is not 4

Comment: The exception typically means the version mismatch between client and server.